# Django and python3

Tags: python, django, web-frameworks

I'm currently testing frameworks to create a big multiplayers game. I choose Django.

But I have a question about the version of Python. I should to create that project from scratch with Python 3.x or Python 2.x?

Python 3.x and Django compatibly is ok, or not production usable for now?

Comment: IMO, it completely depends on whether or not any 3rd party Django apps you plan on integrating are ready for Python 3, and if not, how much work will it take to get them ready.

Comment: See this thread on HN: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5009484

Comment: While it's a good question, I don't think you are going to get a 'correct' answer. Like @Brandon said, if you are going to be relying on any 3rd party modules you will need to ensure they support python 3 too.

Comment: Most development with django is pretty dependent on django features themselves. I don't see how you would benefit from using Python 3 when there are plenty of caveats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't highly suggest going production with Python 3 with Django or for that matter any other framework that requires you to depend on many third party applications, although many have been [ported to Python 3](https://python3wos.appspot.com/), you still may find bugs, which you will likely have to fix or wait awhile before maintainers get to it.

Also, there aren't many compelling reasons to move to Python 3 at the moment, but that I suspect that will change soon with all the [asynchronous work](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/) being put into Python 3.

Django is compatible with Python 3.

Comment: Django itself is, but one of django's core strengths is its plugin ecosystem, which you can easily take advantage of. Many good plugins don't support Python 3 yet.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac that is exactly what I said.

Answer (score 0):

There's at least one issue with Python3 + Django (1.6) + MySQL.

MySQLdb hasn't been ported to Python3 yet.

The other python-only mysql connector mentioned in the Django documentation (MySQL Connector/Python) has a bug in it which might stop it working with fixtures.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72001

It looks like Oracle has closed this bug report by documenting that the problem may occur; so a real fix doesn't look likely any time soon.

So if you rely on fixtures and use MySQL, you'll likely have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest GA version of mysql-connector-python.